# Click for a button does not get bound correctly on first click, but is correctly bound on the second click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-events

I am using  VS2010, MVC3.
I have the following jQuery script to, upon clicking a button, have an `ActionResult` in the controller stream the PDF version of the page to a new window.

However, here is what happens:
When the page first is rendered I get the alerts: "in  hereb1" and a correct url value for actionUrl.
The first time I click on the button, I get the alerts "in hereb2" and "undefined" as value for url, and a new window opens with error for undefined resource.
The third time I click on the button, I get the alerts "in hereb2" and the correct url value (same value as `actionUrl`), and a new window opens with expected result. No error.
Why the first click does not have access to the correct value of `actionUrl`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     alert("in hereb1");
     var actionUrl = '@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.BuildUrlFromExpressionForAreas<MyController>(c => c.GeneratePdf(Request.Url.ToString())))';
     alert(actionUrl);
     $("#btnPdf").click(function () {
         var url = $(this).attr("href");
         $(this).attr("href", actionUrl);
         alert("in hereb2");
         alert(url);
         var win = window.open(url, "PdfVersion");
         win.focus();
         return false;
     });
  });
 </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to open `actionUrl` in a new tab/window the following code may help

```
$("#btnPdf").click(function () {
     //var url = $(this).attr("href");
     $(this).attr("href", actionUrl);
     alert("in hereb2");
     alert(actionUrl);
     var win = window.open(actionUrl, "PdfVersion");
     win.focus();
     return false;
 });
```

What your code does is that gets the url to which the `btnPdf` and opens the url in a new window/tab and sets the `href` attribute of the `btnPdf` to the `actionUrl` if you are trying to do this ensure that already serving page with the `btnPdf`'s attribute `href` alredy set.

Comment: This did not work, but thanks anyway.  The first answer to this post, however, worked.

Answer (score 0):

Switch

```
var url = $(this).attr("href");
$(this).attr("href", actionUrl);
```

to

```
$(this).attr("href", actionUrl);
var url = $(this).attr("href");
```